# callback function using an array, does the function use the updated array?

Tags: javascript, reference

I am debugging my code and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. Therefore I'm just double checking my understanding of javascript.

If I have the following:

```
var myArray = []

$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
     if (myArray.length > 0) {
           //do something 
     } else { 
           //do other thing 
     }
});
```

If I subsequently push/pop items from `myArray` later in my code, do I have to remove and readd the on mousemove listener? Or will mousemove be using the correct reference?

Comment: `mousemove` will use the altered array

Comment: You don't have to remove and readd listener, `mousemove` will use the updated array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All objects in JavaScript (and `Arrays` are objects) are passed by reference. Any changes you make to `myArray`, as long as it's in scope, will be changing the single `myArray` instance. It doesn't matter if it's in a callback.

If that is your desired result, then you are done. If not, you can create a new array and work with that as you need it. If you need something from `myArray` you can create a shallow copy of the array like this:

```
var newArr = myArray.slice(0);
```

Comment: In fact it doesn't matter here that it's an array object. All *closure scope* variables are references anyway. It works with primitive values just as well.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't have to remove and readd the mousemovelistener, your array is in a higher scope (global variable in your case) and so the same reference is shared between mousemovelistener and outer scope.